# Count distinct value with 2 criteria

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to find a JDBC MySQL query that will find distinct values in a particular field, count the number of occurrences of that Feedback and then store it in a array list(if possible or if there are better way to store).

```
Company      Feedback    Person
------       --------    ------
Apple        Good          A
Pear         Bad           B
Apple        Neutral       C
Orange       Neutral       D
Apple        Bad           E
Apple        Neutral       F
Orange       Bad           G
```

Expected result for Apple

```
Company     Feedback     Count
-------     --------     -----
Apple       Good           1
Apple       Neutral        2
Apple       Bad            1
```

Edited to add in my code:

```
//Already call an object from database
rs = db.getSM().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
rowcount FROM predata WHERE company = 'Apple' and feedback LIKE 'G%'");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getInt("rowcount"));

rs = db.getSM().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
rowcount FROM predata WHERE company = 'Apple' and sentiment LIKE 'N%'");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getInt("rowcount"));
```

This method works for me but I'm trying to shorten the whole code without repeating the code all over again

Comment: Maybe this query can help  you `SELECT Company, Feedback, COUNT(*)
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Company;`

Comment: @YCF_L `WHERE Company = 'Apple' GROUP BY Feedback;`

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:java] or [tag:jdbc]?

Comment: this is true @shmosel I forgot this thank you

Comment: you need to use a loop to get the information in a list

Comment: Thanks @ _YCF_L =)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Company, Feedback, COUNT(Feedback)
FROM t
GROUP BY Feedback
where Company='Apple';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query all company-feedback pairs at a time and store them in a `Map`.

Query all pairs with count from the database.

```
rs = db.getSM().executeQuery("SELECT company, feedback, COUNT(DISTINCT person) AS rowcount FROM predata GROUP BY company, feedback");
```

Create a `Map` and loop through `ResultSet` to store the count.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> companyFeedbackMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String company = rs.getString("company");
    String feedback = rs.getString("feedback");
    Integer count = rs.getInt("rowcount");
    if(!companyFeedbackMap.contains(company)){
        companyFeedbackMap.put(company, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
    }
    companyFeedbackMap.get(company).put(feedback, count);
}
```

To get the count of `Apple` company with `Neutral` feedback, simply use `companyFeedbackMap.get("Apple").get("Neutral"); // This will return 2`.

---

OR, instead of `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`, you can create you own `Company` class with company name, `good`, `neutral` and `bad` as its constructor attributes and store the count from the pivoted query sql in an `ArrayList` or anything you need like this

```
rs = db.getSM().executeQuery("SELECT company, SUM(good) AS good, SUM(neutral) AS neutral, SUM(bad) AS bad FROM (SELECT company, CASE WHEN feedback = 'Good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS good, CASE WHEN feedback = 'Neutral' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS neutral, CASE WHEN feedback = 'Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bad FROM predata) GROUP BY company");
ArrayList<Company> companies = new ArrayList<Company>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String company = rs.getString("company");
    Integer good = rs.getInt("good");
    Integer neutral = rs.getInt("neutral");
    Integer bad = rs.getInt("bad");
    companies.add(new Company(company, good, neutral, bad));
}
```

The above sql will return the below result.

```
Company      good        neutral    bad
------       --------    -------    -------
Apple        1           2          1
Orange       0           1          1
Pear         0           0          1
```